# New driver not being utilized

Tags: windows, driver

I finally found a guide on for creating drivers, built it and followed this guide https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2016/april/adventures-in-windows-driver-development-part-1/ to install it on the VM, but when I plug in my device it shows up as a serial port, not what I named it as, so It uses the windows driver instead of mine. How can I get it to use mine?

I'm on windows 10 , I followed the guide exactly up until the part where it said to use" devcon.exe install %filepath%echo.inf root\ECHO " to install it, I just right clicked and clicked install instead, would that do it? I did the same for the certificate.

```
 ;
; USBDriver1.inf
;

[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Class=USBDevice
ClassGuid={88BAE032-5A81-49f0-BC3D-A4FF138216D6}
Provider=%ManufacturerName%
CatalogFile=USBDriver1.cat
DriverVer=

[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName%=Standard,NT$ARCH$

[Standard.NT$ARCH$]
%DeviceName%=MyDevice_Install, USB\VID_2341&PID_8036&MI_00

[SourceDisksFiles]
USBDriver1.dll=1
WudfUpdate_$UMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$.dll=1

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DiskName%


; =================== UMDF Device ==================================

[MyDevice_Install.NT]
CopyFiles=UMDriverCopy
Include=WINUSB.INF                      ; Import sections from WINUSB.INF
Needs=WINUSB.NT                         ; Run the CopyFiles & AddReg directives for WinUsb.INF

[MyDevice_Install.NT.hw]
AddReg=USBDriver1_AddReg

[MyDevice_Install.NT.Services]
AddService=WUDFRd,0x000001fa,WUDFRD_ServiceInstall  ; flag 0x2 sets this as the service for the device
AddService=WinUsb,0x000001f8,WinUsb_ServiceInstall  ; this service is installed because its a filter.

[MyDevice_Install.NT.CoInstallers]
CopyFiles=CoInstallers_CopyFiles
AddReg=CoInstallers_AddReg

[MyDevice_Install.NT.Wdf]
UmdfDispatcher=WinUsb
UmdfService=USBDriver1,USBDriver1_Install
UmdfServiceOrder=USBDriver1

[USBDriver1_Install]
UmdfLibraryVersion=$UMDFVERSION$ 
ServiceBinary=%12%\UMDF\USBDriver1.dll
DriverCLSID={5138ba31-5a05-4a39-b1d0-2f7c0dd59d36}

[USBDriver1_AddReg]
; By default, USBDevice class uses iProduct descriptor to name the device in
; Device Manager on Windows 8 and higher.
; Uncomment for this device to use %DeviceName% on Windows 8 and higher:
;HKR,,FriendlyName,,%DeviceName%
HKR,,"LowerFilters",0x00010008,"WinUsb" ; FLG_ADDREG_TYPE_MULTI_SZ | FLG_ADDREG_APPEND
HKR,,"WinUsbPowerPolicyOwnershipDisabled",0x00010001,1

[WUDFRD_ServiceInstall]
DisplayName = %WudfRdDisplayName%
ServiceType = 1
StartType = 3
ErrorControl = 1
ServiceBinary = %12%\WUDFRd.sys

[WinUsb_ServiceInstall]
DisplayName = %WinUsb_SvcDesc%
ServiceType = 1
StartType = 3
ErrorControl = 1
ServiceBinary = %12%\WinUSB.sys

[CoInstallers_CopyFiles]
WudfUpdate_$UMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$.dll

[CoInstallers_AddReg]
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010008,"WudfUpdate_$UMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$.dll"

[DestinationDirs]
UMDriverCopy=12,UMDF ; copy to drivers\umdf
CoInstallers_CopyFiles=11

[UMDriverCopy]
USBDriver1.dll

; =================== Generic ==================================

[Strings]
ManufacturerName="<Your manufacturer name>" ;TODO: Replace with your manufacturer name
ClassName="Universal Serial Bus devices"
DiskName = "USBDriver1 Installation Disk"
WudfRdDisplayName="Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework Reflector"
WinUsb_SvcDesc="WinUSB Driver"
DeviceName="USBDriver1 Device"
REG_MULTI_SZ = 0x00010000
```

Comment: Where do I find the hardware ID ?That's why I didn't do it as per the guide

Comment: Just connect the device and look into its properties in Device manager. Hardware and compatible IDs are there too.

Comment: I have the VID and the PID referenced in my driver, what else do I need?

Comment: If you ask Device Manager to update the driver for the device and point it at your driver, does it say that the driver is compatible with the device?

Comment: It tells me "Windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date"

Answer (score 0):

Your INF file seem not to contain information about hardware IDs (compatible IDs may also be an option I suppose) of a device your driver supports. You need to specify them, so the system may use them when searching for a driver matching IDs of a newly connected device.

Look into WDK samples for an idea how to do it (the RAMDisk sample may help you if you are writting a function driver). For example, one of my kernel drivers gets loaded for devices reporting RemBus\RAMDisk and RemBus\FileDisk hardware IDs. I instructed Windows to do so by the following part of my INF file:

```
[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName%=Standard,NT$ARCH$

[Standard.NT$ARCH$]
%ramdisk.DeviceDesc%=remdisk_Device, RemBus\RAMDisk
%filedisk.DeviceDesc%=remdisk_Device, RemBus\FileDisk
```

Comment: Sounds Like that's my problem but I set the PID and VID , is that not enough? I'll look through the examples, this is the guide I followed for creating the driver, step 2 is where I thought I defined the IDs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh706184(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I just tried using a compatible ID and visual studio won't sign it, says third party drivers must install using the vid + pid